# Using AJAX to return search form results

Tags: wp-query, theme-development, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm trying to take user input from a search form, build a query based on user input, and then return relevant posts using AJAX.

Right now, the form builds the `select` dropdowns properly. The form content disappears on submission, the loading animation appears, and then the results appear.  The problem I'm having is the actual result that is returned - no matter what I do (even a simple `echo: 'Success';` isn't working), I get a `0` as my return.

Form code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="product_search_form" name="product_search_form" method="post">
  <div id="product_search_form_content">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputCarrierSelect" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Carrier</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <?php sms_populate_carrier_dropdown(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputStateSelect" class="col-sm-2 control-label">State</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <?php sms_populate_state_dropdown(); ?>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="prdlnSelect" value="<?php echo $pl_slug; ?>" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <input class="btn btn-primary" id="submit_button" onclick="product_search();" type="button" value="Search" />
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
function product_search(){
  jQuery.ajax({
    data: jQuery('#product_search_form').serialize(),
    type: jQuery('#product_search_form').attr('method'),
    url:  the_ajax_productSearch.ajaxurl_productSearch,
    beforeSend: function(){
      jQuery('#product_search_form_content').remove();
      jQuery('#product_search_form').append('<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" align="center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh glyphicon-refresh-animate"></span> Loading...</div>');
    },

    success: function(response) { // on success..
      jQuery('#product_search_form').html(response);
    },
  });
  return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
}
```

And from my theme's `functions.php` file:

```
wp_register_script( 'ajax-productSearch', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/ajax-product-search.js', array( 'jquery') );
wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-productSearch' );
wp_localize_script( 'ajax-productSearch','the_ajax_productSearch', array('ajaxurl_productSearch' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));

add_action( 'wp_ajax_productSearch', 'ajax_action_productSearch' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_productSearch', 'ajax_action_productSearch' );

function ajax_action_productSearch(){
  echo 'Success';
  die();
}
```

Is there anything glaringly obvious that I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: 0 usually means the add_actions are not firing at the correct time -probably too late. What hook do you use to load the 'site-specific plugin' code?

Comment: I'm using the `wp_ajax_[action]` hook (I'm actually executing this code in my theme's `functions.php` file, as the theme will never be changed on this site. Updated initial post to reflect this).

Comment: I am not sure this is the same issue you're having, but for me I always need to add this action to get ajax to work properly: add_action('template_redirect', 'register_scripts'); register_scripts for me is the function that has all wp_enqueue_script in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues in your code

You need to add script in `wp_enqueue_scripts` hooks like this -

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_js_script');

function my_custom_js_script() {
    wp_register_script( 'ajax-productSearch', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/ajax-product-search.js', array( 'jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-productSearch' );
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-productSearch','the_ajax_productSearch', array('ajaxurl_productSearch' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
}
```

The second issue is that, you need to add `action` argument in your `jQuery.ajax` data. If your hook is `wp_ajax_my_ajax_hook`, the value of this argument will be `my_ajax_hook`. In your case, it will be `productSearch`. Change your `product_search` function to this -

```
function product_search(){
  jQuery.ajax({
    data: { action: 'productSearch', formData: jQuery('#product_search_form').serialize() },
    type: jQuery('#product_search_form').attr('method'),
    url:  the_ajax_productSearch.ajaxurl_productSearch,
    beforeSend: function(){
      jQuery('#product_search_form_content').remove();
      jQuery('#product_search_form').append('<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" align="center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh glyphicon-refresh-animate"></span> Loading...</div>');
    },

    success: function(response) { // on success..
      jQuery('#product_search_form').html(response);
    },
  });
  return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
}
```

Comment: That did it (can't believe I didn't enqueue that properly, ha) - thanks for helping this AJAX newb out :)

Comment: @andrewdcato Glad I could help.