# Submitting a form, using Ajax, to run a SQL Select query based on user input from the form

Tags: php, ajax, javascript, mysql, forms

I'm creating a web form on my WordPress-powered website, such that by entering a date and some upper/lower bounds into the provided fields, then submitting the form, the page will query a MySQL table, SELECT the rows which fit those criteria and dispense those values into a table on the same page. Unfortunately, I'm having a difficult time understanding what to do to get WordPress to perform this seemingly-simple task.

From the research I've done so far, three things are necessary to query a SQL table from within a WordPress:

1. A form, written in PHP, which resides in the .php file for your page template
2. A function which actually executes the SQL query, added to your theme's functions.php file
3. A segment of Javascript code to tie the above two things together

The website page I've set up to test this form is "http://www.finstability.com/serch/". Here's what I've done so far:

First, the form code:

```
<form type="post" action="" role="form" id="MRISearchForm" class="MRISerch">
    <p style="font-size: 16pt;">Date: <input style="font-size: 16pt;" type="date" name="inDate" value="12/31/2016" width="200" height="32"></p>
    <p style="font-size: 16pt;">Minimum MRI: <input style="font-size: 16pt;" type="number" name="inMRILow" value="70" min="0" max="100" width="200" height="32"></p>
    <p style="font-size: 16pt;">Maximum MRI: <input style="font-size: 16pt;" type="number" name="inMRIHi" value="100"  min="0" max="100" width="200" height="32"></p>
    <p style="font-size: 16pt;">Min. Market Cap: <input style="font-size: 16pt;" type="number" name="inMCapLow" value="" width="200" height="32"></p>
    <p style="font-size: 16pt;">Max. Market Cap: <input style="font-size: 16pt;" type="number" name="inMCapHi" value="" width="200" height="32"></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="mriSearch"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" style="font-size: 18pt;">
    <input type="reset" style="font-size: 18pt;">
</form> 
<div id="search_results"></div>
```

Second, the function in functions.php:

```
function mriSearch() {
    global $wpdb;
    echo "33333";   

    $inDate = $_POST['inDate'];
    $inMRILow = $_POST['inMRILow'];
    $inMRIHi = $_POST['inMRIHi'];
    $inMCapLow = $_POST['inMCapLow'];
    $inMCapHi = $_POST['inMCapHi'];

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM mri_sql_test WHERE Date = %s AND MRIScore >= %s AND MRIScore <= %s';

    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare($query, $inDate, $inMRILow, $inMRIHi) );
    echo $results;
    die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_mriSearch', 'mriSearch' );    //If called from admin panel
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_mriSearch', 'mriSearch' );    //If called by non-user
```

Third, the javascript sequence to tie the above two together. This is the part I'm having the most trouble understanding, as I have -0- prior knowledge of Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){               
  // get our references
  var $form = $('form.MRISerch'),
      $inDate = $('#inDate'),
      $results = $('#search_results');

  // AJAX search call
  function do_search() {

    // grab the query value from the search field
    var search_text = $search_field.val();

    // do a POST ajax call
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
      data: ({
        action: "mriSearch",
        search_text: search_text
      }),
      success: function (response){
        console.log(response);
        $results.html(response);
      }     
    });
  }

  // on submit, do the search but return false to stop page refresh
  $form.submit(function(e) {
    do_search();
    return false;
  });

})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Most of what I've been able to piece together so far I've learned from looking at similar examples, such as [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/189867/using-ajax-to-return-search-form-results). If someone would kindly provide me with an explanation, ideally with example code I can copy and modify, for whatever I'm missing in order to complete this task, I would be most appreciative.

For reference, clicking the Submit button on the above-linked page currently just causes the page to reload and adds a bunch of hash to the http address, which implied to me that the SQL query in the second block of code is probably not being executed.

Comment: Are you sure the jquery selector works and your JS console has no errors? Also why do you return false on submit? Have you tried the standard `e.preventDefault()` in jQuery events?

Comment: Thanks for the tip about using the console to check for errors. Judicious use of console logging let me see what the code was doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `e.preventDefault()` instead of `return false;`

```
$form.submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    do_search();
});
```

Comment: That helped, thanks! The other thing I had to do was move this snippet of code up to the top of the <script> section; I had it at the bottom.

Comment: The position of this is not relevant for your issue. It could be anywhere in your script after `var $form = $('form.MRISerch'),`, above or after the `do_search` function